# Were there any changes on how top 10/20/30% on careers are calculated?

Tags: support, jobs

I found this question:
[How are percentiles calculated in Careers 2.0?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80401/how-are-percentiles-calculated-in-careers-2-0)

It says:

- take all the candidates in our system (which only includes people who have at least a total score of 5 in that tag.)
- sort by their total score in the tag
- figure out where you fall

I am looking at [one of the small tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/iphone-privateapi) where I active answered. Based on Top Answerers, there are at least 20 people with score 7+. So, it should show something like top 20% for me. However, it doesn't.

Am I missing something?