# What does it mean when it says "Top n% for [tag]" on my careers profile?

Tags: support, jobs

It looks impressive enough but what does this actually mean?

On my profile this shows instead of the tags I've seen at some other peoples profile:

> Top 30% for sql-server

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80401/how-are-percentiles-calculated-in-careers-2-0 and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121074/top-x-in-tag-rules-for-the-tag-to-be-taken-into-account (should be somehow merged so there is single, correct, answer, so not using hammer to close it for now)

Comment: @ShadowWizard here is was looking for % sign and not finding jack ****. thanks for the links ;)

Comment: Search tip #212: relevant tag(s) plus a keyword. In your case: [`[careers] [support] "top" is:question`](http://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bcareers%5D+%5Bsupport%5D+%22top%22+is%3Aquestion)

Comment: @ShadowWizard "search tip #212" ?  Is there an actual list..? (Or is this just a "Space Corps Directive...")

Comment: lol, I was actually inspired by [this](http://aselia.wikia.com/wiki/Dwarven_Vows), finished the game only recently and consider it an awesome game. :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### It means you are top [xx]% of *reputation* for that tag. That's it.

**So it's not an indication of how smart you are relative to everyone else?**

No.

It can't mean that because everyone else doesn't contribute to **Stack Overflow.** So how can Stack Overflow make a statement then about a person's knowledge in relation to everyone else's knowledge? Reputation isn't an IQ score. It's a gamification score to encourage further community involvement. It's an indicator of community acceptance of their ideas.

Yet just like everywhere else in life, the best answers aren't always the most accepted. Also there isn't always only one answer to a problem, but multiple solutions which bring their own set of pros and cons. It is then upon the post author to accept an answer. Does this always mean the accepted answer is the "best" answer? No, yet the community's highest-voted answer doesn't necessarily mean it's the "best" answer either.

Reputation isn't a qualitative indicator of a person's post. Generally it does hold true that the highest voted answers tend to be of a higher quality, yet this isn't always true. What we can say is that **reputation is a clear indicator of the community's acceptance of a person's answer.**

**So what can people infer from the top percentage (and reputation)?**

A few things actually:

1. **The person likes to help.** This is a person who enjoys helping others get answers to their problems. Employers want people like this on their team.
2. **The person is knowledgable about the topic.** While we can't infer a person's knowledge in relation to everyone else, we can make the inference that the person knows enough to answer a question and feel confident enough to share that answer. Employers want people who are knowledgable.
3. **A person's knowledge has been *somewhat* vetted.** I say "somewhat" here because most answers deal with specific problems and rarely address holistic approaches. Yet we can most likely posit that a person wouldn't understand the details without understanding the whole. Reputation is an indicator of the community's acceptance of a person's knowledge, ostensibly by other people who are knowledgable on the subject or looking for an answer. Employers want some way of verifying that a person is actually telling the truth when they say I know [xx]  technology. This is one way for users to communicate to employers (and employers to see from developers) that they do know said technology.
4. **The person can communicate well enough.** This is a big one that rarely gets a lot of attention. While we're not saying the person is the next *New York Times Bestseller* author, but they obviously can write well enough to communicate they understand the problem, provide a solution, and even share the "why" behind the solution (The "teach a person to fish versus giving them a fish" concept).

Answer (score 2):

It means you are in the top n% of answerers (by reputation) for that tag.

It's an indication of how much you <strike>know</strike> participate relative to everyone who answers questions in that tag.

Comment: Sorry but the answer from @Hynes is too good not to grant him the green check mark.