# Why are the two percentages different?

Tags: discussion, tags, jobs, data-explorer

When I see my [StackOverflow CV](https://stackoverflow.com/cv/pritam-banerjee-296385) in SO I see I am ranked in top 20% in Java.

But when I run [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/527106/is-there-a-way-to-see-the-what-percentage-you-are-in-a-particular-tag?tagname=java&UserId=1475228) I see my rank in top 1.5%. Why this anomaly?

Comment: I want to say the SEDE data is only updated weekly, but I don't know if it would explain that big of a difference.

Comment: @JasonC Yes, big difference. 1.5% can be used in resume not 20% :P

Comment: This is explained here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80401/how-are-percentiles-calculated-in-careers-2-0 (in essence, it's because the percentage is among Careers users, i.e. Jobs, formerly Career, takes into account only users with Jobs profile/CV, not all users. So naturally,  those will have better stats)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Ok. Now I got it.